# percentage of the population usage

Tags: verb-agreement

I was wondering which is correct. 20% percent of the population is a man or 20% of the population is men. I understand that a singular verb is to be used but...

Comment: Twenty percent of the population are men.

Comment: Please show the community any reference that shows why a singular verb is to be used or tell us why you think a singular verb is to be used.

Comment: How about in the case of 1% of the population..?

Comment: Only if the population consists of one man and four women.

Comment: I would pesonally say " 20% of the population are men" but I've been lead to believe a singular verb is needed because population is a mass noun.

Comment: Are you asking about "are" vs "is" or "a man" vs "men"? Please [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311243/percentage-of-the-population-usage) to make it more clear.

Comment: man or men@Rathony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What complicates this sentence is the usage of the word **population**, which is singular. If you were to replace it with **people**, it would be obvious that you are talking about a number of people, so you need a plural- "20% of the people are men".

If you wanted to describe the whole population rather thsn the individuals that make it up, you would have to use a singular verb and an adjective - "20% of the population **is** male".

Comment: "20% of the population is male" is arguably the more correct answer, given that we read "%" as percent (one part in a hundred) and that this is the subject of the sentence, modified by the adjectives "20" and "of the people".  Everyone is, not everyone are.  Nevertheless, everyone would probably agree that "20% of them are men" is a nice trick for avoiding "20 out of every 100 of them are men".

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd go with: "Twenty percent of the population are men."

If you find that a bit ticklish, you can change that to: "Men make up 20 percent of the population."

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Please improve your answer.  I particularly like "Men make up (or comprise)  twenty percent of the population."  It's a great suggestion that just needs some support.